# Detect sim card change (codenameOne)

Tags: codenameone

I would like to detect if the sim card has been changed using codenameone API.
Is there any API available for it. Like read some SIM card details and store it for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Not for most OS's but on Android you can use `getMSISDN` in `Display`. This would cause a "phone permission" to popup which is a "scary permission".